# clean exit - waiting for changes before restart?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

please tell me how to solve this problem why doesnt it start and say restarting

```
         const express = require('express');                                   
         const mongoose = require("mongoose");
         const app = express();
         const port = 3000;
                 app.post("/employee/add",(req,res)=>{
                     console.log("request is here");

                 })

        mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017//class-project")
            .then(()=>{
             app.listen(port),()=> {
             console.log('Server is listening on port ${port}');
             }
            })
```

Comment: See if my answer helps you and I will vote to close this question as it is probably caused by a typo.

Comment: Also, tt's recommended that you post the exact error message in the question, formatted as code (instead of just "say restarting")

Answer (score 0):

```
   mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017//class-project")
            .then(()=> {
              app.listen(port, ()=> console.log('Server is listening on port ${port}');
            })
```